# How to programmatically page to next/prev page in jqGrid

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

Is there a jqGrid method that will skip to the next/prev page of rows.
I was trying to programmatically click the button itself with jQuery, but didn't succeed yet

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To go to page 123:

```
grid = $("#grid");
grid.setGridParam({
    page: 123
});
grid.trigger("reloadGrid");
```

NB: The grid behaves oddly if you go to a page for which there is no data.

Comment: Can I find the current page number, so I can use N+1 as the next page number. Also how do I know how many pages are there in total

Comment: $("#grid").jqGrid('getGridParam','page') returns current page and $("#grid").jqGrid('getGridParam','lastpage') returns the total number of pages.

Answer (score -2):

You can use  `$("#next").click();` to trigger next page.